# JavaScript search form multifunctioning

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an issue that I am not able to solve.

I have to modify a search form that is using Ajax.

[Here's a fiddle showing the setup](http://jsfiddle.net/dompl/J3FtG/)

For no there was two filter fields : `keyword` and `job_location`. I have added another filter field `job_title`.

Unfortunately the results are not pulling anything from the database for `job_title.`

Comment: Does `job_title` have a value *before* it's sent to the server? If so, has the server side been updated to support the `job_title` parameter?

Comment: @James Yes, I have updated the form with HTML on jFiddle. Thanks for heling.

Comment: The s_job_title id is on another page then job_title. Last one is on results page.